# free space getting low for no reason

Tags: windows

I have just noticed that my C drive is getting full, whereas it still had 30 GB free space 3 days ago.
Given last days activity I can't find any reason for this.
**Now I realize that my C free space is getting lower and lower even though there's no current activity on my PC (except that it's turned on).
Every 2 minutes, I lose approximately 100 MB of free space, even though I don't download anything.**

I launched my antivirus and I have closed my internet connection in order to see if the free space would stop decreasing, but it continued decreasing at the same pace.

I checked the task manager and notice there was a software running which I think was named "One Drive setup.exe" (during the past weeks, I had many pop up windows saying I had to update onedrive, but there was a problem with the auto update etc... but I didn't car because I don't even know what OneDrive is and I don't think I use it). So I killed this running task.

I thought it had stopped the loss of free space (I even gained 100 MB), but the decrease started again.

Now I connected to Internet again.

I got 300 MB free space back and now it seems constant since 4 minutes. Maybe these little ups and downs can be due to the current antivirus scanning.

But what can explain the loss of 30 GB during the past 2 or 3 days?

Could it be windows update? How can i check this with windows 10? 
Could it be a virus or something bad?

Please, answer quickly, i only have 17GB left :-(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Windows OS are you using? 
Turn off/ disable System Restore point, this way you will able to recover some space. Other than use CCleaner (https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) to clean your system.

Comment: windows 10. CCleaner was hacked a few days ago, wasn't it? kind of scary for a helping tool

Answer (score 0):

They release patch I believe. But u also can use built in disk cleanup tool(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026616/windows-disk-cleanup-in-windows-10). 
Also uninstalled OneDrive/Google Drive unless u actively use this service. OneDrive sync with cloud files so that u can use those off line.